# masscan with docker unable to detect file

Tags: penetration-testing, penetration-tools

i am running masscan in docker with alias when i typed `masscan -iL ips.txt -p80,443` ips.txt: No such file or directory but the ips.txt exist on same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can type following command

docker run -v /root/file.txt:/mas/mass.txt -it --rm adarnimrod/masscan -iL /mas/file.txt